# Is it possible to use Ant Design with vanilla JS?

Tags: antd

From what I can see, Ant Design is [only available](https://ant.design/docs/spec/introduce#Front-end-Implementation) if you're developing a React, Angular, or Vue application.  I can't find any information on using the components in a vanilla JS project like you can with most other general CSS frameworks (Bootstrap/Semantic-UI/Foundation/etc).

Is it possible to use Ant Design independent of React/Angular/Vue?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use it independently, but you are welcomed to implement such feature:

> We welcome the community to implement our design system in other front-end frameworks of their choice.